# Windows Update Cleanup fails to clean up

Tags: windows, disk-cleanup

I run Disk Cleanup as administrator and it showed 3.5G under Windows Update Cleanup. However, it didn't clean this space (or any that I can see) and on the next run showed 2.04M. Is there any way to check which is correct and to force cleanup? `C:\Windows\winsxs` folder *is* huge (14.9G).

Comment: You cleaned what was age to remove the rest should be kept for system stability....cleaning out the folder is really dangerous you cleaned out 3.98GB not sure what you expected it removed exactly what it said it would

Comment: @Ramhound "you cleaned out 3.98GB" No. As I say in the question, the amount of free space didn't increase.

Comment: Have you rebooted? Which version of Windows? 14.9GB isn't particularly large.

Comment: It had to have increased because you delete 3.48GB worth of data.  Something else is using up your disk.  Disable your page file and hibernation file and see if that helps.

Comment: Which Windows? 7 or 8?